# Create an array from a file read

Tags: c#, arrays

I currently have a `.txt` file with the layout:

```
text: value
text: value
text: value 
text: value
etc...
```

How would I go about getting an array of just the values please?
or even an array of:

```
Arr[0] = text
Arr[1] = value
Arr[2] = text
etc...
```

I understand the stream reader class etc and how to get a whole line, but when I split, it doesn't let me add to the split array to add more `text: value`pairs.

Comment: "but when i split". Can you show that code? In this scenario, a simple split function should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another way. This approach only keeps one line of the file in memory at once:

```
string filename = "test.txt"; // Use your filename here.
int n = "text: ".Length;

var array = 
    File.ReadLines(filename)
    .Select(item => item.Remove(0, n))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split a line with space then you'll get array ['text:','value','text:','value'...]. You can then simply iterate through those array and modify odd indexes by deleting last char (which is ':').

EDIT:
If you have new lines at the end you can split every line with space and do what I wrote above. You can also implement simple algorithm and read line and then process it iterating through every char and if you current char is ':' then you put your substring to an array, then iterate and ignore space and then iterate and put your second substring to an array's next index. Then read next line and repeat what I wrote...

Comment: Hello :)
Initally i had a split on the ':' and it would split into the array but it would keep overwriting the elements in the array and leave me with the last pair.

I have used @matthew answer and this works well :)

Thank you for the suggestions all.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common approaches to achieve your goal.

The First:
You can iterate through EACH LINE of the File, splitting it on the ":" character, trimming both sides and storing the values in the array.
E.G. with a LINQ-Query like this:

```
string[] array = File.ReadAllLines("TextFile1.txt")
    .SelectMany(line => line.Split(':')
    .Select(s => s.Trim()))
    .ToArray();
```

Or with use of regular expressions (RegEx):

```
var matches = new List<string>();
var regex = new Regex(@"^([^:]+):[ \t]+(.*?)[ \t]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
var matchResult = regex.Match(File.ReadAllText("TextFile1.txt"));
while (matchResult.Success)
{
    matches.Add(matchResult.Groups[1].Value);
    matches.Add(matchResult.Groups[2].Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

the second approach is more flexible...

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> ExtractValues(string path, char separator = ':')
    {
        if (path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("path");

        var values = new List<string>();

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var index = line.IndexOf(separator);
                if (index >= 0)
                {
                    values.Add(line.Substring(index + 1));
                }
            }
        }

        return values;
    }
```